# SimpleInjector MVC Controller injection keeps giving compiler error

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I'm using simple injector, however my MVC Controllers keep failing with a class specified in the constructor due to no 0 argument constructors.

My code in `Global.asax` to register all controllers and simple injector

```
        container = new Container();

        // register MVC controllers
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();

        // register our objects
        container.Register<ICacheManager, MemoryCacheManager>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.RegisterSingle<ILogger, NLogLogger>();

        container.Register(typeof(UsersOnlineModule));

        container.Verify();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

My test controller class

```
public class SidcProjectController : Controller
{
    public SidcProjectController(ICacheManager cm)
    {

    }
}
```

SearchController

```
public class SearchController : SidcProjectController
{
    [HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult Query(string query)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Trying to compile this solution gives me a compiler error:

> Error 2   'sidc.Framework.Web.Controllers.SidcProjectController' does
>   not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments  D:\Projecten\Software
>   Development\Source\Workspaces\SIDC\sidc\sidc\Areas\Projects\Controllers\SearchController.cs   10  18  sidc

SearchController is of type SidcProjectController that acts as a base and requires ICacheManager to read values from the cache.

Comment: Please update your question and add the  exception message and stack trace.

Comment: You claim you're getting a compiler error, but your question suggests its a runtime error, which would not be a compiler error.

Comment: can you provide more details about MemoryCacheManager class?

Comment: Error 2 'sidc.Framework.Web.Controllers.SidcProjectController' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments D:\Projecten\Software Development\Source\Workspaces\SIDC\sidc\sidc\Areas\Projects\Controllers\HomeController.cs 10 18 sidc

Comment: So is this a compile error or exception? Please add enough context to this question for us to understand and reproduce. In its current form, your question is too vague for anyone to help you.

Comment: Please show content of SearchController.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving a compiler error because your SearchController inherits from SidcProjectController which has a non default constructor. Simple Injector will not inject anything into this constructor simply because it can't. Simple Injector has no knowledge of the inheritance and the clr, as the compiler correctly warns, need you to create the base when it hasn't a non default constructor. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115(v=vs.100).aspx).

You should new up the base class from the constructor of the implementation like this:

```
public class SearchController : SidcProjectController
{
    public SearchController(ICacheManager cm) : base(cm)
    {
    }
}
```

Understand that you need to do this for every dependency you need in your base controller. Therefore think twice if you really need a base class! And if you really need one it should not be dependent on anything or you will violate [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and run into trouble pretty quickly.

So while my answer will compile I strongly advise against using this approach, because your base class will become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: So you recommend placing the code of of the base controller in each and every depending controller? Or now when I think of it, it probably should move to a httpmodule or so. All it is doing is reading part of the URL and preloading details to place in the viewbag for the Layout page.

Comment: I have modified my code to use a common BaseViewModel for my properties required in my layout page, this works nicely and gives me strong-typed models as well (which is cleaner than ViewBag) However every Action in my controller requires this code to fetch all common properties, what is the recommended way to keep this as clean and re-useable as possible?

Comment: @user3188048 I would say you'll define some singleton service to fill these properties and return a fresh baseviewmodel. It would be very nice if MVC had some default behaviour for this where we woudl be able to decorate the returning models with some cross cutting concerns.

Comment: I'm now having a Helper object that I insert in each controller. This contains what you describe and I also encapsulate my Entity Framework object with references to each of my Services (BLL) that essentially are LINQ queries to get the right data and then (mis)use the same helper object kind of as a unit of work. However I do not have any repo's. All my queries go through the services, I think this seperates out quite nicely.

Comment: Please post a new question to give the community the oppurtunity to provide you with some feedback